# Conexão recusada com o Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics-api

[image: https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js [HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable 18 ms].]

Não está contando acessos e com o Firebug aparece essa mensagem:

> https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js [HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable 18 ms].

Fiz vários procedimentos e nada.

Comment: Pode postar o código aqui que você inseriu na sua página pro tracking e onde exatamente você inseriu? Sua conta do Google Analytics é válida e as informações estão corretas referente ao seu site (URL, etc)?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="pt-br"><head>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-24265129-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
 </script>